# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python

***Aclaración:***Abul4fia tiene razón, faltaba darle el valor a k, posterior a esto el código funcionó correctamente. Muchas gracias.

estoy desarrollando un código para hacer interpolación por cubic splines.Todo funciona bien, pero luego trato de meterlo todo dentro de una función nueva (la idea es que usando esa función pueda graficar una curva) y cuando lo ejecuto me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "b.py", line 44, in <module>
f = intpcs(x,y)
File "b.py", line 38, in intpcs
return np.vectorize(evalSpline(x))
File "b.py", line 34, in evalSpline
i = findSegment(xData,x)
File "b.py", line 30, in findSegment
if x < xData[i]:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array,zeros,ones
import scipy.linalg as la
def intpcs(xData,yData):
    def curvatures(xData, yData):
        n = len(xData) - 1
        c = zeros(n)
        d = ones(n+1)
        e = zeros(n)
        k = zeros(n+1)
        c[0:n-1] = xData[0:n-1] - xData[1:n]
        d[1:n] = 2.0*(xData[0:n-1] - xData[2:n+1])
        e[1:n] = xData[1:n] - xData[2:n+1]
        k[1:n] = 6.0*(yData[0:n-1] - yData[1:n])/(xData[0:n-1] - xData[1:n]) - 6.0*(yData[1:n] - yData[2:n+1])/(xData[1:n] - xData[2:n+1])
        m = np.diag(d) + np.diag(e,1) + np.diag(c,-1)
        (t,u) = la.lu_factor(m)
        f = la.solve(m,k)
        return f

    def evalSpline(x):
        def findSegment(xData, x):
            iLeft = 0
            iRight = len(xData) - 1
            while 1:
                if(iRight-iLeft) <= 1:
                    return iLeft
                i = int(np.floor((iLeft + iRight)/2))
                if x < xData[i]:
                    iRight = i
                else :
                    iLeft = i
        i = findSegment(xData,x)
        h = xData[i] - xData[i+1]
        y = ((x - xData[i+1])**3/h - (x - xData[i+1])*h)*k[i]/6.0 - ((x - xData[i])**3/h - (x - xData[i])*h)*k[i+1]/6.0 + (yData[i]*(x - xData[i+1]) - yData[i+1]*(x - xData[i]))/h
        return y
    return np.vectorize(evalSpline(x))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
f = intpcs(x,y)
xnew = np.arange(0,9,0.1)
ynew = f(xnew)
plt.plot(x,y,'o',xnew,ynew,'.')
```

Comment: Hay algo mal en tu código (aparte del error que mencionas en la pregunta), pues dentro de la función `intpcs()` defines la función `curvature()` que sin embargo no usas por ningún sitio, lo que es un mal síntoma, y por otro lado dentro de la función `evalSpline()` haces uso de un vector `k` (accedes a `k[i]`, por ejemplo), que no veo que reciba valor en ningún sitio. Revisa el código no sea que al copiarlo&pegarlo te hayas dejado algo fuera. También mira aquí cómo pegarlo correctamente para que se formatee -> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE